# Jersey - Validation is not working for Query Param

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

It looks like validation for Query Param is not working, but validation for Body is working (Using @POST)

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Foo get(@PathParam("id") Integer id,
               @NotNull @QueryParam("param1") Integer param1) {
....
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger validation add the `@Valid` annotation to the param.

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Foo get(@PathParam("id") Integer id,
               @Valid @NotNull @QueryParam("param1") Integer param1) {
....
}
```

Comment: Valid is for validation cascading so that inner properties of the object annotated with Valid are validated. So this is not a correct answer. See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13614

Comment: @marians27 hm seems you are correct. Any idea why the validation wasn't working before/ what is the correct answer?

Comment: I can't say without more details. @richersoon I see you accepted the answer, does it really work with Valid annotation and without not?